# Ionic and Mapbox API

Tags: cordova, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use the Ionic framework to create both ios and android applications. I need to use map box in conjunction but the cordova plugin for mapbox breaks when I try to use it. In the build log it says the at the os may not be the correct kind but it is. I am testing on Galaxy S5 and on Ripple. The app is able to be launched on ripple but will not run the map and it will not even build on to the actual piece of hardware. Does someone have some kind of tutorial or example code for mapbox with ionic so I can troubleshoot and get a map to appear on my application.